# fatch db data and Match date with today, red if lastdate is expired

Tags: php, date

Can Someone Help in this regards?

1. How can I add a color on the row's `lastdate` cell if it's already expired?
2. Also how can I sort the records by date in descending order with format (day-month-year)?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

include('connect-mysql.php');

$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM job ORDER BY id DESC";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die('error getting data');



echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td><b>Description</b></td><td><b>Source</b><td><b>Fee</b><td><b>Last Date</b></td><td><b>Details</b></td></tr>";
$serial = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $serial;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['desc'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['src'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['fee'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['lastdate'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<center><div  class='view'><a href='details.php?id={$row['id']}'>";
    echo "View";
    echo "</a></div></center></td></tr>";
    $serial++; //increment Serial Number by 1 on every pass 
} 

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :)

### -- Table structure for table `test`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`lastdate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `test`

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `lastdate`) VALUES
(1, '10-03-2018'),
(2, '08-03-2018'),
(3, '07-03-2018'),
(4, '06-03-2018'),
(5, '11-03-2018');

<?php
include('connect.php');
$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY lastdate DESC";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die('error getting data');

echo "<table border='2' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5'>";
echo "<tr><td>Last Date</td></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$lastdate=$row['lastdate'];
$todays_date = date("d-m-Y");

$today=strtotime($todays_date);
$exp_date=strtotime($lastdate);

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
if($exp_date < $today){
echo "<font color='red'>"."<strong>".$row['lastdate']."</strong>"."</font>";
}
else{
echo $row['lastdate'];; 
}
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
} 

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Is it possible to show ads between rows? I want to show 1 ad after five rows.